# What does this mean and how to tackle it?

Tags: tensorflow

ValueError: Tensor("transpose:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("transpose_5:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32).

Comment: You might want to include your code to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: It means you are trying to operate together two tensors that belong to two different graphs, as the error states. Please post a reproducible code example if you want more help, as it is impossible to tell how to fix your problem without further information.